# STS application applicationContext.xml validation

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring

I noticed that STS succeed in validating applicationContext.xml files even when xsi:schemaLocation is not specified. I halso checked in STS Preferences > XML Catalogs and spring xsd are not specified there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

     <xbean id="cross" class="mypackage.spring.Cross" scope="prototype">
    </xbean>

</beans>
```

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: How can the xml be validated?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend writing Spring smoke integration test. It doesn't have to test anything, just context startup (you would be amazed, how many errors it discovers).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the validation is performed because the xsd are being cached, check under `Preferences->General->Network connections->Cache`.